# Styled components API - withComponent vs. as

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I've stumbled upon a question regarding the Styled Component API updates in version 4:

- [`withComponent`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#withcomponent) which was handy to use, is now deprecated
- [`as`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop) is the introduced alternative to it

But as far as I understood `as` is meant to be used on a JSX template level whereas `withComponent` was used within a styled component declaration.

So what is the suggested workflow in situations like following:

```
const BaseComponent = styled.div`
  color: red;
`;

const HeadingComponent = BaseComponent.withComponent('h4');
```

assuming that we use `<HeadingComponent />` in **a lot** of different places.

Would it mean that instead of having a second styled component, declare a React component using the `<BaseComponent as="h4" />` and instead of reusing the styled component, reuse the React component?

So transfer usage of `withComponent` into creating a new React component using the base styled component with `as` attribute?

Thanks in advance,

Andreas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I personally prefer reusing the React component with the `as` prop, it could be easier for you to just refactor the usages into ``` BaseComponent.attrs({ as: 'h4' })`` ```.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this:

```
const Anchor = styled.a`color: hotpink;`
const Span = Anchor.withComponent('span')
```

do this:

```
const styles = css`color: hotpink;`

const Anchor = styled.a(styles)
const Span = styled.span(styles)
```

`styled-components` v6 [removed `withComponent`](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/releases/tag/v6.0.0-beta.11), so I expect this question to get a lot more attention.